# Which branch to make a pull request?

Tags: git, pull-request

If I do a pull request to someone's repository, should that in general be to the master branch or to the "latest" branch? Or is it not possible to say in general?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on where the main development is being done. On most projects in Github, this is normally the `master`, or `dev` branch (if there is one). So what you do is:

- You create a fork of the repository
- You make your fixes on whatever the base branch you'd like to have the fixes is on (of course, if you like, you can also create a feature branch for that development against the base branch of interest as well, depending on your style of working)
- Commit
- Push
- Open a pull request with the original project

In most evolved companies, or projects with a more sophisticated way of working you often have something like this:

- A stable `master`
- A `dev` (or otherwise named) branch for developing the code
- Feature branches based on the `dev` branch
- When you are ready to make a release, you merge `dev` into the `master`

Of course, this is a reasonably simple example. You could have extra layers of branches before merging into the `master` as well. For example, a `stable` (or also called `release`) branch could be the additional step between merging `dev` into `master`. Such an intermediate branch could be used to rollback some features from the development branch during releases, or apply urgent fixes to the release which is about to be cut, without having to limit the commits to the actual development branch.

As a conclusion, it really depends on the team/company approach for working and this is quite different between projects/companies, so you'll have to most-likely figure out where the most active, (or most recent work), is going on. If that is still not apparent, as pointed out by Philippe, you can always contact the team and tell them you'd like to fix something and ask what branch to base your work on.

Comment: My first thought was `dev` branch - many projects have it. I wouldn't send a patch to `master` branch without checking if there is no `dev` first.

Comment: I agree, let me update it!

Comment: @ArkadiuszDrabczyk: Is this a bit better? :)

Comment: yes, now it is :)

Comment: Communication is good ;-) If this very good answer didn't help you, perhaps you could do how github team advise you, open an issue to ask and tell the team on what you plan to work. They could always give you good informations. And you could ask them to add this information to the `README.MD`. That will be useful for future contributors...